# JsonSchema, prevent value in array from being the same as a property

Tags: jsonschema

I have the following JsonSchema I've been working on,

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "JSON schema for DLC Metadata",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "description": { "type": "string" },
    "uuid": {
      "description": "The unique identifier for the DLC",
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 36,
      "maxLength": 36,
      "pattern": "^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})-([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})-([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})-([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})-([a-zA-Z0-9]{12})$"
    },
    "version": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        { "type": "integer" },
        { "type": "integer" },
        { "type": "integer" }
      ]
    },
    "depedencies": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "description": "The uuid that this DLC depends on",
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 36,
        "maxLength": 36,
        "pattern": "^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})-([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})-([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})-([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})-([a-zA-Z0-9]{12})$"
      },
      "uniqueItems": true
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "uuid",
    "version"
  ]
}
```

and I want to ensure that none of the values in `dependencies` is equal to the `uuid` property of the dlc metadata, Is there a way to ensure this condition, and how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema doesn't have a way to do this out of the box, but if you're using 2020-12, you can do it with a vocabulary that defines a custom keyword.

If you're using .net (specifically the [JsonSchema.Net](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything) library, which is mine), then there's already such an extension: JsonSchema.Net.Data.  Check out the [docs](https://json-everything.net/json-schema#a-vocabulary-for-accessing-data-stored-in-json) for more info.

(I'm on mobile now. I'll edit with an example when I'm in front of a computer.)